# body blinks on ipad when modifying overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

i got a problem with the following function on iPad :

```
var resetOverflow = function(scroll) {
   if (Modernizr.touch){
     if (scroll) {
       $("html, body").css({overflowY: 'scroll'});
     } else {
       $("html, body").css({overflowY: 'hidden'});
     }
   }
 }
```

When i make a call to that function on iPad (tested on ipad 2 & 3), the whole body is blinking to a black screen for a very short time. Is there a way to remove it ? I tried to change the jquery selector to $('body') without success

EDIT

here's the click handler which call the function

```
$('#home .menu>li>a, #home h1 a').off('click').on('click', function(e){
  var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');

  if(href == '#society'){
    showPopin();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  pauseVideos();
  resetOverflow(false);
  menu(e);

  require(['router'], function(router){
    if($(e.target).attr('data-tree')){
        router.menuHighlightCurrentPosition($(e.target).attr('data-tree'));
    }
  });
});
```

I assume it's about the resetOverflow function, because the effect disappears when i comment the call. But i still need to change the overflow, so can i get rid of this blink and still play with overflow ?

Comment: When are you calling `resetOverflow()` ?

Comment: the problem is occuring in a click event:
$('#home .menu>li>a, #home h1 a').on('click', function(e){

Comment: Can you include that code as well, since it may be something else or a combination of this and that.

Comment: added click event and some explanations